# Error: "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Smallicon" while creating Coded UI Test Project (UWA)

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I'm getting error dialog box "*Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Smallicon*" while trying to create '*Coded UI test Project (Universal Windows)*' project using updated yesterday (June 28, 2016) MS Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25421.03 Update 3. Please see enclosed screenshot.

Any hints how to solve the subject issue?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx indicates that coded ui is not available in professional edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm after testing on same environment that a Pro version displays the error message while an Enterprise one succedeed in project's creation.

(I guess it was too complicated to display "Feature is only available in Enterprise edition, please upgrade." instead of "Hello I'm a non related message that tells you nothing about your current problem.")